# Capturing Screenshot with background using webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I know how to take screenshots using `TakesScreenshot`, but it doesn't have any additional parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the api, I don't think kwargs are an option.

http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/TakesScreenshot.html

The only option appears to be output type -- file, bytes, or base64.